# How to ship an executable from a dependency with Poetry?

Tags: python, packaging, python-poetry

I'm using Poetry to manage my application dependency and virtual environment.

Although the PyPI package publication can be handled seamlessly with Poetry, I'm unable to find docs on how to solve my case:

- My app depends on a package that includes an executable.
- The dependency package builds the executable during the install phase of Poetry.
- In the dev environment, this executable can only be installed to the cache folder via `poetry install`.

The app's runtime needs to use this executable, but I'm not sure how to extract this executable and all its own dependency and ship it with my app, by just using Poetry's built-in features.

Is there a poetry command or pattern for this scenario?

Comment: when you say "executable", do you mean a dependency that is not a python package?

Comment: @Arne It is part of a python package, but the package builds it during the install phase of Poetry. Then to ship it to end-users, I wonder how I should make it available to `setup.py` simply by using Poetry's export feature.

Comment: ok so I am not 100% sure, but I think you have to build an sdist with poetry (`poetry build` should create one by default) and then use a system packager to create the right built distribution for the os you are targeting. I can't write an answer because I have no experience in that specific area and would need a lot more info from you (which os, which executable exactly, how are you building it..), so [the docs on `bdist`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/builtdist.html) can probably guide you better than I could.

Comment: @Arne Thanks a lot. It's very nice of you. Really appreciate it!